# Axis/Log4J FATAL messages not being logged

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, axis

I am trying to change my log4j settings to log FATAL level messages, however the one message I'm waiting to see in the logs doesn't appear event though it seems to be marked as FATAL.

My log4j.properties excerpt:

```
### Setup Axis Log
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=FATAL, AXISCONSOLE
log4j.additivity.org.apache.axis=false

log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE.File=D:/temp/debug/axis.log
log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE.Append=true
log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AXISCONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] AXIS %-5p %c - %m%n
```

The error, when log4j is set to DEBUG, is:

```
2018-04-25 12:38:15,232 [ajp-bio-8012-exec-1] AXIS DEBUG org.apache.axis.EXCEPTIONS - AxisFault:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 19; The prefix &quot;ns0&quot; for element &quot;ns0:authToken&quot; is not bound.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 19; The prefix &quot;ns0&quot; for element &quot;ns0:authToken&quot; is not bound.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
```

I can see that the code calls

```
 org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
```

at one point, however it doesn't seem to log when AXIS is set to FATAL. What am I missing?